# 2 Bulma.io dropdown nav items

Tags: css, bulma

I'm building a page using Bulma. Unfotunatly, I found something weird. When I hover over one of the two dropdown menus containing class "is hoverable", both of the dropdown menu's trigger, displaying both menu's at the same on.

I would like to only dropdown the one I hoover my mouse over. How could I make this?

```
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                        <a class="navbar-link">
                          Projects
                        </a>
                        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                                <a class="navbar-item" href='/projects'>
                                  Projects
                                </a>
                                <a class="navbar-item" href=''>
                                  Edit
                                </a>
                                <a class="navbar-item" href="/projects/create">
                                  create
                                </a>

                  </div>
                    <a class="navbar-item" href="/contact">
                    Contact
                  </a>
                <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                        <a class="navbar-link">
                          Vue.js
                        </a>
                        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                                <a class="navbar-item" href='/vue'>
                                  Page 1
                                </a>
                                <a class="navbar-item" href='/vue2'>
                                  Page 2
                                </a>
                                <a class="navbar-item" href='/vue3'>
                                  Page 3
                                </a>
                          </div>
```

Comment: You've nested the second `.has-dropdown` inside the first. You need to close the first div.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not closing the divs correctly, two `</div>` were missing.
See below, now you can align them horizontally with respective Bulma classes/structure.

```html
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
  <a class="navbar-link">
    Projects
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-dropdown">
    <a class="navbar-item" href='/projects'>
      Projects
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-item" href=''>
      Edit
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-item" href="/projects/create">
      create
    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 
<a class="navbar-link" href="/contact">
  Contact
</a>

 <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <a class="navbar-link">
      Vue.js
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
      <a class="navbar-item" href='/vue'>
        Page 1
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item" href='/vue2'>
        Page 2
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item" href='/vue3'>
        Page 3
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```